# How to identify my correlationId or identifier if logic app is triggered from Service bus

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

I am working on a azure portal.
I have below requirement

1. Trigger logic app from postman
2. Then it will go to service bus
3. And from service bus another logic app will get triggered

Note : - if i trigger first logic app using postman then we can easily get correlationId or TrackingId as header
However problem is with second logic app that is triggered using Service Bus

Answer (score 2):

After reproducing from my end. I could able to achieve by following the below process. From the first Logic App's Service bus connector try adding "Correlation Id" from Add new parameters.

[image]

So when the message is triggered in the second logic app this Correlation Id will be included. Below is the flow in my 1st Logic App.

[image]

Flow in my 2nd Logic App

[image]

**RESULTS:**

***In 1st Logic App***

[image]

***In 2nd Logic App***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick response